# get product to show in Magento ver 1.7

Tags: php, magento, csv, magento-1.7

I am working on a development version of a Magento 1.7 store, and have used Magmi to upload all of my products.  My problem is that I can't get the images to show up on the front end.  In my csv file I have:

```
'image' => "/magento/media/catalog/product/import/".$row['isbn13'].".gif",
'small_image' =>  "/magento/media/catalog/product/import/".$row['isbn13'].".gif",
'thumbnail' => "/magento/media/catalog/product/import/".$row['isbn13'].".gif",
```

where $row['isbn13'] is the isbn number of the book that I am selling.  I have uploaded all of the images to that folder, and I am having no success.
How do I get the images to be view able in both the front and backend?  Do I need to go in and edit any of the files?

Comment: 1) Magento Import/Export is fast so there is no point in using magmi 2) I believe some more columns are needed in there related to the gallery part

Comment: I have over 80,000 items, import/export takes me over 24 hours where Magmi takes me about 30 minutes.  I only posted a small portion of my csv related to the images.  I do have columns for Store, website, attributes and category_id, what others do I need?

Comment: Magento Dataflow Import/Export is slow, Magento Import/Export (different section in menu) is faster and the data is consistent. The documentation for Magmi is here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor ask them for support.

Comment: those are absolute paths, try and omit the leading slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for magmi you'd better

- remove /magento/media/catalog/product/import part of your paths in the csv (since it's a common dir).

  - if you don't want to touch your csv, you may have a look at value replacer plugin that can perform operations on csv values before magmi handles them. (here i would suggest using the advanced syntax for columns image,small_image & thumbnail & perform some str_replace of the unwanted prefix with emtpy string)
- set plugin local images from parameter to:  media/catalog/product/import (no leading / , magmi will know then it's relative to magento root)
- now the csv (or transformed values) will only have image names. the directory where magmi is supposed to find them will be correctly set. then magmi should be able to import images correctly.

Of course, you need to install & configure the image processor plugin to import images !!!!!

Comment: If all of my images are in the folder magento/media/catalog/product/import do I need to set an external reference to them in the csv?  I have made the changes noted above and am getting a lot of warnings that images are not uploading, which I think is because I am only referencing the images, not uploading the actual image itself, is this correct?

Comment: in fact there is a copy of the images from the import directory to where the magento catalog structure expects them to be.the warnings should tell why it cannot copy.

Comment: the errors said not found skipping item, which is possible.  However, I checked a few that I knew had images, and they are not appearing, is there anything I need to do in the back end to make them appear?

Comment: i think the better for you is to send me an email with an access to your setup , since i think you should be missing something obvious that i could not figure out without having a look at the configuration

Comment: I would love to, however it is on my localhost, I would be happy to send you and screenshots that you would like to see.  Thanks for all the help and the great program.  It does save me a bunch of time.

Comment: I am going to upload everything to my live server as a test environment and once that is done I will get you the info.  Thanks again for all the help.